# Can long running async HTTP calls cause too many objects in generation 2 of garbage collection?

Tags: c#, async-await, garbage-collection, clr

In a recorded webinar on a messaging architecture, the presenter mentioned some issues with synchronous and long http/web requests where GC keeps on waiting on the response objects and eventually move them to the Generation 2 of GC.

I was curious if the same happens with the async await calls also as it is not about CPU threads but more of a memory leak thing.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{

    string response = await LongHTTPRequest();
    Console.WriteLine(response);
}

public static async Task<string> LongHTTPRequest()
{
    await Task.Delay(12000);
    return await Task.FromResult("Response from RPC");
}
```

Comment: What are your question about?

Comment: If I call some http based service (RPC) from my application (using async-await),which takes long time  what is the effect on GC? When should I think of decoupling it from my application using some messaging queue/bus etc.?

Comment: You can inspect the scenario that are you interest by the GC class, for example, use (GC.GetGeneration)[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.gc.getgeneration?view=netcore-3.1] method. Also, I don't think the problem in the scenario in question cause a memory leak.

Comment: @Marlonchosky obviously I can, but this is a topic where experts discussion matters.

Comment: Unless your option is not calling the service, you should be comparing the effects of calling it synchronously and asynchronously.

Comment: @PauloMorgado Yeah I am asking the same, the difference in the behavior of GC in synchronous and asynchronous.

Comment: The state machine that gets generated to handle the async flow will end up on the heap if you have a task that is not completed. This state machine needs to be kept alive until you get a response or a timeout/error occurs. If this is long running and you are hitting frequent GCs/running low on memory, then potentially could lead to a gen 2 move.

Answer (score 0):

WebServers and Multitasking are a odd combination:

1. On the one hand, it heavily uses implicit Mutltithreading. Your average ASP.NET Server has a Threadpool, in the size of tens to hundreds of Threads *per CPU Core*. And then *another ThreadPool* the same size (but that one is rarely used). On the request level, it is [embrasingly paralell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel).
2. On the other hand, you really should avoid *explicit* Multitasking on the server side, if you can. The entire design is for requests to be:

   - received
   - processed
   - results sent
   - dropped from memory ASAP, to not tie up resources to long

If you look at the page Lifecycle for [ASP Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178472(v=vs.140)#life-cycle-events), you can see it. But it aplies basically to all Web Page Development. And WebServices. And Databases, for that mater.

Explicit multitasking would either:

- keep the request in memory for too long, causing resource starvation (including memory, but I am more worried about umanaged stuff like DB Connections here)
- not return in time for the response, being dropped and thus a waste of CPU time and memory for while it lasted

If you got to do Multitasking with a WebPage, do it on the client side. Usually involving some AJAX or similar, that queries a seperate WebService. That gives you Multitasking without any risk of resource starvation.

The average WebPage with Images is already a example. We could totally [send images inline](https://www.bigfastblog.com/embed-base64-encoded-images-inline-in-html), with the rest of the page. We have know how to do that, since the beginning. But we rarely do. The server sends out a pure HTML page witout inline image, but with a lot of image URL's. And then the Browser - the client - will asynchronously download each and every image, CSS file andJavaScript code piece (the later two are more likely to be embedded, but not a guarantee either). One seperate request at a time.

Comment: For some reason, every time I say those words - uses implicit Multithreading, but should not use explicit multitasking - I get downvotes. Propably the people not realizing they have been using other peoples code that did it for them the whole time.